# How do I resolve a duplicate symbol issue for arm64?

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I'm using Firebase analytics with pods and xcode 8. I get the following error:

Directory not found for option '-L/Users/***/Documents/repo/projectName/build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'

5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is the podfile:

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end

target 'ProjectNameTests' do

end

I've tried:
1. Setting build active architecture to NO for pods and YES for project. 
2. Deleting workspace / pods and then reinstalling the pods.

FYI. The pods architecture is "Standard Architectures(64-bit Intel)(x86_64)- $(ARCHS_STANDARD)"

GoogleToolboxForMac is "Standard Architectures(armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)"

Main project architecture is also ""Standard Architectures(armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)"

Playing the compile wack a mole here. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple answer. I had 2 duplicate .m files in the build phases compile sources.